# Update server.xml file of Tomcat using Java

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, jakarta-ee, server.xml

I am new to tomcat Administration.

My requirement is, admin user can upload certificate file that need to be applied to tomcat.

currently, my tomcat server.xml, Connector tag looks like

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/tomcat.p12" keystoreType="PKCS12" keystoreAlias="tomcat" keystorePass="password" SSLEnabled="true"/>
```

at run time admin user can upload a new .p12 certificate file along with password using a web portal provided.
At server side I have to update `keystoreFile` and `keystorePass` arguments of `Connector`tag using java.

So that it takes new certificate file.

In my search, some guys suggested to use 2 server.xml file. some told to edit server.xml file. in tomcat docs it is mentioned as this parameters are configurable in system environment and can be directly updatable.

I tried updating system environment parameter thinking that is the easy solution, but no success (might be I am doing wrong).

Also, I would like to know is there any solution that can apply my changes without tomcat restart.
Can someone help me what is the right approach for this requirement.

Any links where such requirement is handle will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a comment cause it is my suggestion not a full answer but I would run out of space in the comment.

Just to make sure. You want to update the certificate that is used to authenticate your SSL connection, I am asking cause typically tomcat is behind apache and the ssl is handled by apache not tomcat. If you want to add certificate to verify the ssl to a client (cause for example he has self signed certificate) you don't do it on connector.

Wasn't it be simplest, if upon certificate upload you rename it and place it allways at the same path (and use the same password) so you don't have to update server.xml.

You can easily check if the update works without restart (just replace certificate and see what happens) but I doubt it. You could check the source code of the connector implementation (just open the right one as currently they are 3 iplementations), and see if you could modify it to trigger keystore update.

And finally, do you really want to provide such a feature. The less exposed are manipulations of your certificates the safer you are.